# Office365 Compliance Powershell Module Get-ComplianceSearch cannot expose value for $_.ExchangeLocation via foreach loop

Tags: powershell, office365

I am attempting to find all compliance searches done by a singular user in office365 compliance center by using the `Get-ComplianceSearch` module the information i want from these searches are the `Name` of the search and the `ExchangeLocation` which will show what mailbox was searched.

when I use the module on a singular search

`$search = Get-ComplianceSearch -Identity "nameofsearchgoeshere"`
I can return the values i seek:

```
$search.Name
$search.ExchangeLocation
```

I wrote a function to provide that information in a foreach loop style so i could loop through each search as this user has done quite a few.

```
function Get-ComplianceSearches {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string]$Individual
    )
    $complianceSearches = Get-ComplianceSearch -ResultSize Unlimited
    $individualSearches = $complianceSearches | Where-Object { $_.CreatedBy -eq $Individual }

    foreach ($search in $individualSearches) {
        $searchName = $search.Name
        $ExchangeLocation = $search.ExchangeLocation

        Write-Host "Search Name: $searchName"
        Write-Host "Exchange Location: $ExchangeLocation"
        Write-Host "--------------------------"
    }
}
```

when calling the function `Get-ComplianceSearches -Individual "namegoeshere"`
the `$searchName` value is always written correctly and yet the `$ExchangeLocation` is always blank. I have confirmed that running the singular version always returns the expected values but the foreach loop never provides me the information. what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but if you run `get-ComplianceSearch` with any identity, the `ExchangeLocation` returns fine, if not it will be blank.

See the difference between:

1. `Get-ComplianceSearch | ft Name, ExchangeLocation`
   and
2. `Get-ComplianceSearch | Get-ComplianceSearch | ft Name, ExchangeLocation`

So, you need to use `get-ComplianceSearch` inside you "foreach".
Here is an example:

```
$allSearchs = Get-ComplianceSearch | Select-Object Identity
foreach ($allSearch in $allSearchs)
{
  Get-ComplianceSearch -identity $allSearch | where-object {$_.ExchangeLocation -like "*marcelo*"}
}
```